# three of a kind problem help me please

Tags: texas-hold-em

i had (Q-A) and my friend had (9-9) and on the table there was (7-Q-Q-9-2) who wins ?
Because my freind think that the player who has the(9-9) wins the game. is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: I want to know who wins please !

Comment: @AmarBz Read the question on how to determine the winning hand. It explains it.

Comment: you have three of a kind, your friend has a full house, thus you loose. Please read the post on reading hands so you understand how this is so. We always close hand reading questions, its the old teach someone to fish, or give them a fish, we choose to teach.

Answer (score 2):

The best 5-card hand you can make is Q-Q-Q-A-9, three queens with A, 9 kickers. Your opponent's best five-card hand is 9-9-9-Q-Q, full house 9s over Qs. Full house wins.